# Connection error when connecting Postgres container using psycopg2

Tags: python, docker, psycopg2, alpine-linux

I have the following setup:

- postgres:10.4 container
- nestjs container
- python:3.9.14-alpine3.16 container with psycopg2

And all of the container composed with docker-compose.yml.

Also my nestjs app connect do postgres database without any error. But python container is not.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  alyanetworkapi:
    container_name: alyanetworkapi
    image: alyanetworkapi:1.0.0
    build:
      context: ./docker/alyanetworkapi
      args:
        DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
        DATABASE_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_DATABASE}
        DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
        DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "6002:8000"
    networks:
      - alyattes-backend
      - internal
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_DATABASE}
    user: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - alyattes-backend
      - internal
networks:
  alyattes-backend:
    driver: bridge
  internal:
```

Here is the Dockerfile of python container:

```
FROM python:3.9.14-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update
RUN apk add git
RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk
RUN apk add libpq-dev

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk del build-deps \
    && apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++ bash

ARG DATABASE_USERNAME
ARG DATABASE_DATABASE
ARG DATABASE_HOST
ARG DATABASE_PASSWORD

ENV DATABASE_USERNAME=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
ENV DATABASE_DATABASE=${DATABASE_DATABASE}
ENV DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

RUN git clone https://${GITHUB_PAT}@github.com/owner/reponame.git

RUN chmod 775 -R /app

WORKDIR /app/alya-network-api

RUN pip3 install .

CMD [ "python3", "main.py"]
```

Error message:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "postgres" (192.168.112.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this question to reduce the setup, especially the Compose file, to a [mcve]?  For example, do you need the Node or PGAdmin containers to demonstrate the Python issue?  Do you have the same problem if you delete the custom `networks:` and use the `default` network that Compose provides?  What's the least amount of code and configuration that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Okay, I edited my question and cleaned a bit. Thanks for feedback. And unfortunately the default network couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is 192.168.112.2 correct IP of that postgres container, what container ports do you see when you do `docker ps` ?

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work the second time?  If you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, do you see database startup messages after the Python exception?

Comment: After hours of changing the python code itself I spotted that psycopg2 only connect successfully after second connect attempt. So there is no problem of my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile. I only changed the database connection class and it solved. Thanks for help.